# Angular, Promises, foreach in textarea, and keeping processing order

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular, but not to programming. Trying to teach an old dog new tricks :)

I have a textarea where the user enters a list of dictionary words to lookup. There are currently 3 places where it uses their API via $http get and pulls the response from the API. Say I have these in the textarea:

```
computer
fragment
teleport
```

It loops through the textarea and runs "lookupWord()" for each word. All 3 API results are combined, and I generate my own unique ID, as well as including the word at the top of the object. This is so I can put the results in a table, and make the table row's (tr) id the unique ID I generated. There is a "view" button for each row, where when they click it, it pops up a modal with all the details. This process just makes it super simple to match the result in the array of objects, especially if there was a duplicate word.

**My Problem**

My hang up right now, is looping through the textarea and keeping processing order. When they click the start button, I want to disable the textarea and checkboxes on the form, so nothing can be changed in the middle of processing. When it is done, it needs to unlock the form and alert the user it is done.

I don't have it disabling the elements yet, but I am trying to get it to say "Done" after it has looped through and looked up each word. It reports "Done" before everything is actually done :(

Here is some code:

HTML

```
<textarea ng-model="wordlistTextarea" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false" class="form-control" id="wordsTextarea" placeholder="words to research..." rows="10"></textarea>
<input ng-model="checkboxSources.webster" type="checkbox" id="webster-api"> Merriam Webster (Dictionary API)
<input ng-model="checkboxSources.oxford" type="checkbox" id="oxford-api"> Oxford American College Dictionary (Google)
<input ng-model="checkboxSources.forvo" type="checkbox" id="forvo-api"> Forvo Pronunciation Dictionary

<button ng-disabled="!wordlistTextarea" ng-click="startProcessing()" class="btn btn-success" id="pronunciation-submit" preventDefault>Search</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.searchResults = [];    // holds array of objects for later use
$scope.baseApiUri = 'http://apibase.com/api/here';
$scope.checkboxSources = {
    webster : true,
    oxford : true,
    forvo : true
};

$scope.startProcessing = function() {
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.wordlistTextarea, function(value, key){
        //$scope.lookupWord(value.trim());
        promises.push($scope.lookupWord(value.trim()));
    });

    $q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        console.dir(results);
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log('DONE!!');
    });
};

$scope.lookupWord = function($word) {
    Q.all([$scope.getWebster($word), $scope.getOxford($word), $scope.getForvo($word)])
    .spread(function (resultWebster, resultOxford, resultForvo) {
        var randomId = $scope.getRandomId();
        var result = {
            'word': $word,
            'id': randomId,
            'sources': {
                'webster': resultWebster.data,
                'oxford': resultOxford.data,
                'forvo': resultForvo.data,
            },
        };
        $scope.addToResults(result);
    })
    .done();
};

$scope.downloadPart = function(myUrl) {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: myUrl,
    });
};

$scope.addToResults = function(data) {
    console.log('Adding Result:');
    console.dir(data);
    $scope.searchResults.push(data);
};

// -- API SOURCES --

$scope.getWebster = function(word) {
    if ( $scope.checkboxSources.webster == true ) {
        var url = $scope.baseApiUri + '/dictionary?word=' + word;
        return $scope.downloadPart(url);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};

$scope.getOxford = function(word) {
    if ( $scope.checkboxSources.oxford == true ) {
        var url = $scope.baseApiUri + '/oxford?word=' + word;
        return $scope.downloadPart(url);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};

$scope.getForvo = function(word) {
    if ( $scope.checkboxSources.forvo == true ) {
        var url = $scope.baseApiUri + '/forvo?word=' + word;
        return $scope.downloadPart(url);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

**Overview**

Again, my issue is when I click the button for `startProcessing`, it needs to do stuff first (disable the form), loop through the textarea and lookup the words. When done, I need to do more stuff (like enable elements on form, alert Done!, etc).

Additionally, I want to replace the `Q` (I have the library included) for the $q included with Angular. I used `Q` because it has `spread`. As you can see, I use spread to put the results specifically into the object. I don't know if I can use `$q.all()` instead and use `$result[0], $result[1], etc`?

Any questions, let me know. I wrote this quick because I am about to take the kids trick or treating :)

Thanks in advance!

**PS:** Feel free to correct me on bad Angular, or how I should do it better (or correctly). It's the only way to learn and get better ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the promise array is not actually an array of `promises`.
Your `lookupWord` function needs to return the promise it created so it can be watched.

Just add a `return` for the promise it creates.

```
$scope.lookupWord = function($word) {
    return Q.all([$scope.getWebster($word), $scope.getOxford($word), $scope.getForvo($word)])
    .spread(function (resultWebster, resultOxford, resultForvo) {
        var randomId = $scope.getRandomId();
        var result = {
            'word': $word,
            'id': randomId,
            'sources': {
                'webster': resultWebster.data,
                'oxford': resultOxford.data,
                'forvo': resultForvo.data,
            },
        };
        $scope.addToResults(result);
    })
    .done();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but the forEach where I loop through the textarea, is still not finishing before moving on to the rest of the code. I need to stop it until it has the results (lookupWord()) so I can unlock the page when done.

Comment: I actually got it working :) I will update with the solution when I get spare time. Thank you.